# get and show attached video wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need get attached video (by url from Youtube) from post and show it dynamically in same page.
The fact is that I have 2 types of single.php
One of them show posts with thumbnails
[image]

The second one need show video instead of image.

For get image I use this code

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
```

I know, that is not attached file, that is thumbnail. But can I get attached video from post and show it like image?

For example I have post like this

[image]

And I recieve post page like this

[image]

Can I display same video above using any short code?

Comment: I have query.You want to use both for the same post ? Or you want to have either video or image ?

Comment: I want to use only video in posts where is attached video

Comment: So if video is present then use video instead of image otherwise show only an image.Am I correct ?
And can we use plugin to achieve your desire result ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct! I would like not to use plugins if possible.

Comment: There is no way just detect embed video in post and create some short code which display the video ?

Comment: Have you tried [Feature Video Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-video-plus/) plugin ?

Comment: I haven't try any plugin, I hope do this without them)

Comment: It will be easy and fast if you use any plugin :)

Comment: we are not looking for easy ways)))

Comment: I understand, you want post thumbnails get from youtube videos?  If is it your problem, it's possible.

Comment: My problem is:  I want to simply detect, if in post exist embed video? If it exist create any snippet like this '<?php the_post_video(); ?>' and then I can use that video anywhere else on same page.

Comment: You can use `custom field` to add you tube URL.After that you need to retrieve that with the `get_post_meta()` and then you can use something like `<?php echo do_shortcode('[embed]'.$youtube_video_url.'[/embed]'); ?>`

Comment: Place please full code if it easy for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you don't want to use plugin, then you can achieve it with `custom_field`.

So firstly add one custom_field and name it what ever you want(I have used **utube_video_url**).

After adding the field, next step is to enter the **Youtube** URL to that.

Thats's it from the back end. Now its time for coding.

```
<?php 
    global $post, $wp_embed;
    $youtube_video_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'utube_video_url', true); //store youtube URL in variable

    if(!empty($youtube_video_url)): //Check Youtube URL is entered or not
        echo $wp_embed->run_shortcode('[embed]'.$youtube_video_url.'[/embed]');
    else:
        the_post_thumbnail();
    endif;

?>
```

We have stored **Youtube** URL in one variable and then checking whether user has entered **YouTube** URL or not.

If yes, then it will output youtube URL or else it will print **Feature Image**.

**Reference for shortcode**: [Do_Shortcode not working for Embed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22524/do-shortcode-not-working-for-embed)

Let me know If you have any doubts.

Comment: That is what I want, but seems wordpress dont understand us) http://joxi.ru/GrqMKy9tR9J9rz   http://joxi.ru/v29QDNnfRak02G   I do that, but it show post thumbnail, not video.. http://joxi.ru/5mdkoQ3iaW5Kr1 Wordpress couldnt find custom field and load code from `else` ?

Comment: It was working fine in me.Make sure video URL is stored in database.Please check database as well. And try to `echo $youtube_video_url` before if condition.

Comment: Nothing is going on:( http://joxi.ru/zAN04kjF8kRZm9  http://joxi.ru/12M14pNtwBan2J   http://joxi.ru/BA0dORWIvnOoAy

Comment: My guess is it is not getting the `$post->ID`. can you please `echo $post->ID` just before `$youtube_video_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'utube_video_url', true);` line?

Comment: Ok, it got post id. http://joxi.ru/J2bey3aIgzMbm6       http://joxi.ru/V2VnpYgf87GQ2v  I think it cant get post meta(

Comment: If it is getting `post ID` then it should get post meta also. Have you checked your database ? What happened if put manually post ID in get_post_meta ?

Comment: Weird..Have you checked your database ?

Comment: How can I do that? I'm using local server.

Comment: Ok .. I am assuming you are using `MySql` . Go to the `localhost/phpmyadmin` and then in your database `database XYZ` and then click on `wp_post_meta` table(I am assuming you have **WP** prefix) and check for post ID `128`.I would suggest start from end so it will be easier for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67905/discussion-between-rohil-phpbeginner-and-croatoa).

Comment: Its working perfectly fine in my PC ...Screen shot http://postimg.org/image/b9x0hvy6p/

Comment: If you have any query in future and need help, you can comment here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    // add this in your theme functions.php

            function video_yt_shortcode( $atts ){
            ?>
         // for thumbnail
            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $atts['video_id']; ?>/0.jpg">
         //for video
     <iframe width="745" height="400" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo     $atts['video_id']; ?>?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
            <?php
            }
            add_shortcode( 'yt_video', 'video_yt_shortcode' );
            ?>
```

use shortcode
**[yt_video video_id="ytvideo_id"]**

like this
**[yt_video video_id="8KxIHVGch8I"]**

Comment: No, its not that what I want.. I want to get attached video file from post. Like `<?php get_attached_media('video') ?> ` but this code returns array, I want to it would have returned file, not array, that I could paste it anywhere I want in same page...